# How did historians sync up historical dates of different cultures?

Tags: calendar

How do people know, say, that some specific event happened in China 1200 BC? Or the Mayans did something in AD 150? Back then, didn't they all use a different calendar system?

Comment: By tracing the different calendars backwards from a known, synchronised date.

Comment: @Semaphore Ok... but how do they know this date was synchronized? Do you have an example?

Comment: Web search: *chronology*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [chronology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology) (Wikipedia's article on the subject is rather sub-par).

In general, there are two major ways of synchronizing dates.

1. Find an event recorded in more than one calendar.  For example, if a treaty was signed on "a.d. VIII Kal. Oct, Julius et Caesar consulibus" and "7.14.19.11.14", you can establish an equivalence between the two and convert dates back and forth; a sufficient chain of conversions will let you figure out what the date would be in a modern system.  In practice, you'll want multiple dual-dated events, because of errors in the historical record.
2. Find [an astronomical event that was recorded with a date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_chronology).  Total solar eclipses are especially good for this, since they're rare and only visible from a small area.  If you've got even a "within a century or two" idea of how the calendar you're working with aligns to the modern dating system, there's usually only one eclipse that's a candidate.  Again, you want multiple events to deal with possible error (eg. an annular eclipse that was recorded as total, or a "great comet" that was on a hyperbolic orbit rather than the short-period comet you thought it was).

Comment: Addendum: The astronomers use so-called [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) (not to be confused with [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar)). It is also sometimes adopted as a reference where calendars are common, but not regular (eg. switch from Julian calendar to Gregorian with lack of 10 days in 1582, different leap years in Roman calendar etc.).